# Is it possible to tether a D7000 to a smartphone?

Tags: nikon-d7000, tethering, iphone, android, windows-phone

Is it possible to shoot tethered (wired) with D7000 using a smartphone? if yes, which OS, what kind of features and apps are needed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Absolutely. There is a great dongle+app, offered by [TriggerTrap](http://triggertrap.com/).
I purchased it and I'm super happy with it. If I recall correctly, the app is available for iOS and Android.

**EDIT**:

Some of the free app's options are as follows:

- Simple cable release
- Press and hold
- Press and lock
- Timed release
- Timelapse
- TimeWarp (time lapse + acceleration)
- DistnaceLapse (operates on GPS movement)
- Star trail (for exposure control)
- Bramping
- Sound sensor release (!!)
- Vibration sensor release
- HDR modes (including HDR timelapse)
- WiFi slave setup

May I add that it connects to your smartphone's microphone jack. Different signals are sent from your phone (as sounds, obviously), which are converted by the dongle to signals known to your camera as shutter release signals. Simple and genius.

The app is quite a piece of art, too. You get a handful of shooting modes, some of which require the shutter speed mode of your camera to be set to "Bulb Mode".

Plus, if you make sure to set your device on some sort of flight mode, then your boss's call won't mess up the time lapse you've been working on all night long.

Answer (score 2):

If you had the D7100 the answer would be yes via the Nikon Wireless Mobile Utility.

Instead you could use something third party such as: [Trigger Happy](http://www.triggerhappyremote.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Please check out the cam ranger, works great on my d7000 and d600

Answer (score 1):

Yes, get a USB OTG connector for your phone and plug in the camera. Then you can download one of many apps available. I presume you are thinking of android because as with most things that is not supported on Apple devices.

Comment: I asked Nikon support about D7000 connectivitiy by OTG and received the response that it's not compatible connection with mobiles. I am surprised by this answer - is it correct?

Comment: @Alfred - what they mean is that they don't have any software to allow that to happen and certainly wouldn't help you with it if you had a problem.  No reason why it wouldn't be possible otherwise.